# Classification of data with incomplete label sets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

There is such a problem: we have to process multi-label classification (assignmet of tags) of text articles, using some pre-labeled training set. But for many texts in the training set, should be assigned more tags, that it was done by their authors.

For example, there is a text about war medicine, and there is assigned only the text "war", and tag "medicine" is omitted.

Are there any common, conventional methods to deal with such data?

Comment: Semi-supervised learning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning

Comment: There is usually considered the case, when some data are labeled properly, and some are not labeled at all.

Comment: Which is basically the problem you are dealing with from a per-class perspective. Your example of `war medicine` is unlabeled from the `medicine` class' perspective. One way to go would be to treat every binary 1-vs-all classification problem as semi-supervised and use whichever technique you like most.

Comment: Well, well, In normal SSL I have some examples, in which I know, that they are NOT "medicine". Here I cannot say it so confidently.

Comment: This is exactly the scenario of PU learning, a branch of semi-supervised learning. The following reference is one of my favorites: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/posonly.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Based on the question and your comments, you can consider every 1-vs-all classification problem as a so-called [PU learning problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PU_learning) (**P**ositive and **U**nlabeled). PU learning is a branch of semi-supervised learning in which you only have labels of the positive class and (typically a lot of) unlabeled instances.

Every tag is a class in your case. Instances associated with said tag are positive for the associated 1-vs-all classifier, all others are unlabeled. In your example: `war medicine` is a known positive for the `war` class and an unlabeled instance for the `medicine` class.

Here is a simple but comprehensive reference on the subject: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/posonly.pdf